# wsnet simulator: Segmentation fault (core dumped) during installation

Tags: compiling, gcc, segmentation-fault

I installed wsnet simulator about one month ago and everything was OK (I had any problem). 
Now I uninstalled wsnet ( sudo rm –r /usr/local/wsnet.2)
I want to install it again and I follow install steps in [this](http://wsnet.gforge.inria.fr/installation.html) web page.
in step 3 when I use make command I get this error :

```
rng.c: In function ‘create_rng’: 
rng.c:164:14: error: variable ‘r’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable] 
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors 
make[3]: *** [wsnet-rng.o] Error 1 
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/administrator/wsnet/src' 
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/administrator/wsnet/src' 
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/administrator/wsnet' 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Because of this error I disable (clear) -Werror flag in configure.ac files and I type         “make” command again. With this hack it works and “make” process finishes without any error. or I use gcc.4.4.7 and it compile code without any warning.
Then I type another command “sudo make install ” and it install wsnet in its location. 
NOW when I run every simulation config files such as cbr.xml xy.xml etc. I get this error :

```
...
Entity 'battery' (9) 
using model : energy_linear 
using plugin : /usr/local/wsnet-2.0/lib//libenergy_linear.so 
author : Guillaume Chelius 
version : 0.1 
description : Linearly decreasing battery 

Environment 
using propagation : range 
propagation range : 30.000000 
using interferences : interf 
modulation : none 

Bundle 'sensor' (0) 
worldsens : 0 
mobility : static 
number of entities : 7 
static 
battery 
omnidirectionnal 
up : radio 
radio 
up : mac 
down: omnidirectionnal 
mac 
up : routing 
down: radio 
routing 
up : cbr 
down: mac 
cbr 
down: routing 
***Segmentation fault (core dumped)***
```

I think this error occurs after I updated my OS (Ubuntu) using update manager. For example gcc compiler in this version gets warrings as an error. 
when I run this program with gdb I get this back trace :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 
0xb7ee2e5e in gsl_ran_flat () from /usr/lib/libgsl.so.0 
(gdb) bt 
#0 0xb7ee2e5e in gsl_ran_flat () from /usr/lib/libgsl.so.0 
    #1 0x080504c9 in uniform () 
#2 0x0804fd0d in get_random_x_position () 
#3 0xb78e07dc in setnode () 
from /usr/local/wsnet-2.0/lib//libmobility_static.so 
#4 0x08054d9c in parse_nodes () 
#5 0x0804e938 in do_configuration () 
#6 0x0804d827 in main ()
```

I roll back to pervious version of gsl,gcc(4.4.7) library but it don't solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried a `sudo make`? Maybe some directories are write protected for normal users.

Comment: for install wsnet I use `sudo make install`  but for make it NO

Comment: You can edit src/rng.c in the wsnet directory. I commented the switch case statement for r and r itself out. It compiles, but I don't know how it affects functionality.

Comment: I commented it later and it worked but segmentation fault not solved.

Comment: Do you run simulation file truly?

Comment: No, I just compiled the program.

Comment: If it is no hard for you Please run one simulation files. and get me a feedback :))

Comment: There is a crash at: `(gdb) up`
`#1  0x000000000040a854 in uniform (rng_id=0x1, parameters=0x66d090) at probabilistic_distribution.c:92`
`92     return gsl_ran_flat(r, args->a, args->b);`
`#2  0x0000000000409661 in get_random_double_gsl (rng_id=0x1, distribution_type=11, parameters=0x66d090) at rng.c:295`
`295     double result = distribution(rng_id, parameters);`
`(gdb) 
#3  0x0000000000409e03 in get_random_x_position () at rng.c:427`
`427     double result = get_random_double_gsl((void *)DEFAULT_RNG, UNIFORM, args);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem.

You must change the code of the file `rng.c` in the directory `/wsnet/src/`.

You must put this code:

```
rng->r = r;
    if (seed) {
        rng->seed = seed;
        gsl_rng_set(r, seed);
    } else {
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        gsl_rng_set(r, tv.tv_usec + tv.tv_sec);
        rng->seed = tv.tv_usec + tv.tv_sec;
    }
```

in the function `create_rng` below the switch condition and above the `hadas_insert`.

After you compile whithout put the `-Werror` flag to clear.

It works for me and I do not have one "segmentation fault".